# PayPal IPN History

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm searching for an IPN on the IPN History page, and when I select "Last 5 Days" for the search window I get several results.
When I select "Last 28 Days" I get nothing. What's up with that? Is there a reliable alternative to this garbage?

Comment: Same problem... did you figure out a fix?